# Are the Linux community/universe repositories significantly less safe then the main repositories?

Tags: malware, linux, virus, audit, package-manager

If so what makes community/universe less safe? Is there less testing or is it simply less safe because more people could put malware in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't scare you if you're worried about safety of packages. Though I do not recommend using it since it's not officially supported.
**Universe** is community maintained software, that is to say "*not officially supported software*".

I recommend you read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) article so you'll understand the differences between **Main**, **Restricted**, **Universe**, and **Multiverse** repositories.
Good Luck